# How can I find the equations of these cubic graphs?

Tags: graphing-functions, cubics

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK2Px.png)

How can I find the equations of these cubic graphs as seen in the image above?

Comment: Consider their derivatives. How many extreme points does each one have?

Comment: What does inserting $ \ x = 1 \ $ and $ \ x = -1 \ $ into the curve equations give you?   You can use that information to find values for $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ , since the coordinates of points on the curves are marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to “find” here are the values for $a$ and $b$ (or rather, $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$)

Hence, you plug in the points other than the origin (as that simply yields $0=0$) and you get a system of two equations each.

The first graph, for example, yields two equations: $-1=-27a+9b$ and $5=a+b$. From there, solve for the values $a$ and $b$ and substitute them into the equation.

Comment: Thank you that really helped ;)

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.